# Protecting Secret Data from compromise

Tags: php, security, apache, directory

I am currently developing a PUBLIC and OPEN SOURCE software using PHP/MySQL. I have a couple of important SECRET TXT files in a folder. I use them in the software, but problem is that they are also readable by anyone who knows folder and file names:

```
 secret_folder \ my_data.txt
```

I need to hide them against everyone who might be trying to get secret data without permission. I found this way (keeping all secret folders under a unique folder):

```
 U3IPpe8J_2573HkBfR0iYteH8X \ secret_folder \ my_data.txt
```

Unique key will be changing for each website (remember that the software will be open source and public).

Is it good enough for security, or should I use HTACCESS as well? If yes, how can I use it; or do you have any better idea?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ might be a better place to ask

Comment: @mario: That is incorrect. The files are *not **visible** in directory index*, but they are publicly accessible if you know the correct URL. You may be thinking of the `^.ht` rule, which prevents access to files like `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` - that is in default config, but only applies to files starting with `.ht`. Although it is simple to create such rule as you suggest, it is __not__ in the default config, and saying that it is is misleading at best.

Comment: @Piskvor: You're right. Doesn't work on my server either. There used to be a default setting for `<Files .*>` in Debian or earlier Apache configs. But it goes to show that it's a bad idea to rely on defaults.

Comment: @mario: Yeah, used to be, but that's some time ago. Also, it was distro-specific (haven't seen that in RHEL's default config of Apache, IIRC).

Comment: Why are you putting secret files in an open source project? Are you trying to hide this from people who are using your software or their end users?

Comment: @Citizen: "Open source" != "all data must be public". I'm using an open source accounting program; does that mean everyone has a right to see my accounting data? Yeah, didn't think so either.

Comment: @Citizen -of course end-users. It's analytics results -not passwords; but it's important as well.

Comment: @Piskvor I understand the definition of open source. "Hiding files" != protecting data.

Comment: @Dino beytar, if you provided some more details about the purpose of this data, you might be able to get some suggestions on how to best handle it. I assume you are aggregating this data on your origin server?

Comment: @Citizen - This is public software, so every user's data is stored own server. I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember, *Security Through Obscurity Is Not Security*.  So no, it's not good enough.

Add a deny rule in `.htaccess` for the `secret_folder` and be done.

So, your `.htaccess` would include:

```
<Directory /secret_folder>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
<Directory>
```

Even better still would be to move `secret_folder` above the web root (so it's not served at all).

```
/public_html/index.php
/secret_folder/my_data.txt
```

That way it's literally impossible for anyone to request `my_data.txt` through Apache (they could if they hacked PHP code, but not directly through the web server).

Comment: better yet, add a deny, but the store the data in 'secret/my_data.php' prefixed with <?php exit; ?>- then if someone does bypass the deny they won't see the data.

Comment: @symcbean: fair point.  But if they get past the deny with a deny all, you have other things to worry about since they have likely compromised Apache itself to do that...

Comment: Though problem with that is that if you're careless and modify my_data.php with Ultraedit or a program which retains a backup, that backup will not be interpreted as php but downloaded directly, allowing anyone to read it.

Comment: I think we can agree that the best option is to not store the data inside of the web-root.  But if you must, deny the whole directory...

Comment: if I not store my data inside of the web-root, how can I reach it from PHP? What's the way?

Answer (score 2):

For protection of individual files use .htaccess like this

```
<Files my_data.txt>
order deny,allow
deny from all
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
satisfy any
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to help secure the files is to not have them as text files. Maybe put the data required in a structure in a php file. The server will interperet this code rather than serve it up as a txt file.

I have to concur with the other commenter: obscurity is not security.